# Installing font packages

Tags: ubuntu, fonts

I'm trying to install several font packages (*frontproto, inputproto, kbproto, renderproto, xproto, xetproto*) in an Ubuntu 20.04 system using either `apt` or compiling them from source. However, I don't know any source and `apt-cache search` is coming back empty.

Comment: Compiling a font package from sources ? Err ? What do you mean exactly ? What sort of files did you compile with what sort of compiler ?

Comment: The compiler is GCC so you can compile other apps as usual. What I know about these fonts is that their compilation (from whichever method is chosen) should create a frontproto.pc (or similar) file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aren’t font packages, they’re development packages shipping `pkg-config` configuration files (`kbproto.pc` etc.), among other things.

On Ubuntu you need to install `x11proto-dev`:

```
sudo apt install x11proto-dev
```

Comment: I thought that they were fonts but maybe it's something else for the X11 environment. Anyway, the system already has x11proto installed (2019.2-1ubuntu1). Some of those files (kbproto, inputproto, renderproto, xproto) are at /usr/share/pkgconfig but the other 2 (frontproto and xetproto) are not in any subdirectory.

Comment: Are you sure those are the names you’re looking for? I suspect you’re after `fontsproto.pc` and `xextproto.pc` instead.

Comment: You're a 100% right. I'm just tripping myself in a really clumsy way.